# Rspec tests failing when using amazon ses mail sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I recently switched over a rails app to send mail through amazon ses. The sending of the mail works fine, however the tests are failing around the mail items with the following error:

`TypeError:
       can't convert Fixnum into String
     # (eval):3:in 'send_raw_email'`

I have the test environment mail settings set properly to :test

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

I can prevent the errors from happening by not sending emails, but then I get errors about the mail not being delivered.

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
should_change -> { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size } do
   result should have changed, but is still 0
```

Gem versions are below:

```
rails (3.2.12)
rspec (2.8.0)
cucumber (2.3.3)
aws-sdk (1.33.0)
```

Any suggestions on what is going on, or how to work around this. If any other info is needed let me know. This worked fine before I switched the sending of mail to use amazon ses.

EDIT:

The tests that are failing, are all that involve an email being sent using .deliver

```
BlahMailer.send_invite(team).deliver
```

This is inside a model and controller which the tests just call the associated route in the controller or call the associated function in the model. Not sure what else to show, since the error is showing its coming from send_raw_email which is the ses function, not any code from the app.

EDIT 2: More code

Here is one of the tests, in this example it sets up the factory for the model and each test.

```
before :each do
  subject = Factory(:ticket, action_type: 'name_change', team_name: 'test123')
end
```

Here is the factory in rspec

```
Factory.define :ticket do |ticket|
  team = nil
  ticket.team { team = Factory(:team) }
  ticket.creator { team.captain }
  ticket.subject { Factory(:team_assignment, team: team, user: Factory(:active_user)).user }
end
```

And then here is the code in the model around where the email is sent

```
%w(requested approved cancelled accepted).each do |state|
  define_method "notify_#{state}" do
    TicketMailer.send("#{action_type}_#{state}", self).deliver
  end
end
```

I have tried putting in straight text for basically everything having to do with the mailer, just to make sure there are no issues with that. If you need anymore of the model or the actual mailer let me know. I just really cant figure out where this is dieing. My only conclusion is its just a bug with the older versions of the aws sdk and rspec gems. I even tried replacing aws-sdk with newer versions but was still unsuccessful in getting anything else to work.

Comment: You'll need to show more code for anyone to help. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37216571/edit) your question to include both the method you're testing and the test or tests that are failing.

Comment: Added more, not sure what else I can show you since all the call is doing is doing .deliver and worked prior to me changing the deliver_method to :amazon_ses. Could this be a problem with the aws-sdk gem?

Comment: What is `team` in this case? Including more code context would be helpful.

Comment: What does it matter what is in team? It was just an example. I think at this point I am just going to delete the tests since sending amazon ses emails breaks rspec.

Comment: Sorry, I have added more code to help if need be, let me know if providing anything else is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false`, so no deliveries are being made and therefore `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` will always be an empty collection.

If you want to test email deliveries, then set `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true` and use an interceptor to ensure you're not sending emails to users.

```
lass SandboxEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    recipients =
      if Rails.env.test?
        [
          "user@example.com"
        ]
      end

    message.to = recipients
    message.cc = []
  end
end

unless Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.test?
  ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(SandboxEmailInterceptor)
end
```

Comment: Please re-read my question, I only set them to false to test something and it did fix the errors other than new ones popping up in regards to the emails not being sent.